# When I launch my ASP.NET Core MVC app written in C# in a Docker container (building with the release flag), the CSS doesn't load

Tags: c#, css, docker, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a mostly boilerplate ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app. The app is supposed to have a video playing in the background BEHIND all of the landing page's components. This is some of the view in my `Layout.cshtml`:

```
<body>
    <video playsinline autoplay muted loop id="bgvid">
        <source src="assets/ftrcomp.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

  ...

</body>
```

Also the CSS for the video looks like this:

```
/* User added start
-------------------------------------------------- */
video {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
/*-------------------------------------------------- 
User added end*/
```

The video loads perfectly BEHIND everything when I run the `dotnet watch run` command which runs the app in `development` mode.

When I run the app in docker via this Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy everything
COPY . ./
# Restore as distinct layers
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "amaranth.dll"]
```

The picture is a huge block in the foreground ABOVE all of the other content pushing all of the components down below, meaning that the css isn't loading.

I'm assuming that the css isn't loading because the Dockerfile builds the app with the `release` flag.

So how do I get bootstrap and all of the other css to load in `release` mode or is something else causing this css not to load?

Comment: Are you copying the css file to the output directory? `Copy to output directory: Copy always`

Comment: Yeah I just checked. In the docker container `app/wwwroot/css/site.css` has the `User added` code

Comment: Have you used browser dev tools to compare the results?

Comment: Yeah see here: https://imgur.com/oEBom6f